# How do I use React Router Dom to navigate to a new page as a result of a Switch Case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, switch-statement, react-router-dom

Essentially when a form is submitted I want the page to navigate to a different page as a result from a switch statement.

```
switch (real_input_value()) {
  case 'Help':
    console.log('Displaying list of available commands')
    user_input_resultsHelp()
    <Link to="/"/>
    break;
}
```

All the components in `react-router-dom` have to go into the html area and not the javascript area, so how do I navigate to a new page using javascript inside of this `switch` statement?

Component code:

```
const App = () => {

  const input_command_logic = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    switch (real_input_value()) {
      case 'Help':
        console.log('Displaying list of available commands')
        user_input_resultsHelp()
        <Link to="/"/>
        break;
  }

  return()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `switch` statement is a `form` element's `onSubmit` callback it will need to issue an imperative navigation action. For this import and use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function in the component, and issue the navigation action in the handler.

Example:

```
import { ..., useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const MyComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    ...

    switch (real_input_value()) {
      ...

      case 'Help':
        console.log('Displaying list of available commands')
        user_input_resultsHelp()
        navigate("/");
        break;

      ...
    }

  };

  ...
```